# Perl: How is "start perl.exe <filename>" different from "perl.exe <filename>"

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I'm quite new to perl, and I've asked a friend about this and he said something about "parlor execution". What does this mean?

EDIT:

This is in Command prompt

Comment: You are talking about commands in the the `cmd` shell in windows, I assume. You might want to specify that. Do you mean the exact command `start perl.exe <filename>`, or did you mean `start perl.exe filename`?

Comment: Type `start /?` to see the help file for the start command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`start` causes Windows to create a new command prompt window to run the command, freeing up the original prompt. For example, open a command prompt and compare `ping -t 8.8.8.8` to `start ping -t 8.8.8.8`.